# Edit war over citation: direct list vs. quoted list

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10043890/revisions), which is a copy/paste answer from a cited webpage. The answer is cited as "do these things, and see this page for more information," with a link to the source.

My experience on other SO sites is that this is bad form, so I edited the answer to encase the list in a blockquote.

It was re-edited to remove the blockquote, and re-mask the source as a related webpage.

So I edited it again. And it was un-edited again.

Am I missing something? Copy/paste answers are supposed to be properly and clearly cited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you're entirely correct; if it's a quote it should be made obvious that it is one. You should flag the post for moderator attention using the other option if this happens *continually*; a moderator will be able to lock the answer to stop this from happening. As Boltclock comments, if it's just a single rollback you can [`@` comment an editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and explain why it's quoted. This has the benefit of sign-posting the point for future editors.

You could have also made it more obvious that this is a quote in the answer, [please see my recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10043890/7). You can also comment to state that this is a quote and as such, should be quoted.

Comment: Please don't flag a *single* rollback that you disagree with - use @ to inform the editor in a comment first, then flag if they insist on being difficult.

Comment: Fair point @bolt, updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take this path next time -- I didn't realize you already edited it.

Comment: Before I posted this @ashes999 :-).